# Python - issues with numbers in pathnames

Tags: python

I need to open all PDFs in a certain directory, so I first generate a list of the file paths using os.path:

```
filenames = [
    normpath(join(directoryname, filename))
    for filename in listdir(directoryname)
    if filename.lower().endswith('.'+extension)            
    ]
```

So an item in that list looks like this:
D:\\Folder\\2010\\file.pdf

Then I'd like to open each file in a for-loop:

```
for file in filenames:
    PdfFileReader(file(file, 'rb'))
```

but there seems to be an issue with the 2010, because I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Folder\\x810\\file.pdf'
```

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
PdfFileReader(file(r'D:\\Folder\\2010\\file.pdf', 'rb'))
```

how would I do that in the above example where the path is passed as a variable?
Or are there any better ways to do this?

I'm using Windows and Python 2.6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to expand a little bit on what you mean by “using a variable for the pathname”, unless you just mean a variable will get set to your string `p = r'D:\…'` and then used to open the file `file(p, 'rb')`.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you could also simply use forward slashes as path separators on Windows machines as well.

Comment: I had already noted that in my answer, but will make it more obvious since it was hidden in parentheses.

Comment: I should have read your answer first before commenting. ;-)

Comment: I cannot run your sample `for` loop because it replaces the builtin `file()` function with your `file` variable, so that `file(file…)` is just your string filename value trying to call itself as a function.

Comment: @Brandon Oh boy, that was a stupid choice of a variable name and changing it solves the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The backslash is special in C-style strings like Python uses, just like in C++, C#, and Java.  Either use a double-backslash to say “yes, I really mean a backslash,” not the character code `\201`, or use an `r''` string that does not interpret backslash sequences:

```
'D:\\Folder\\2010\\file.pdf'
r'D:\Folder\2010\file.pdf'
```

Note that this issue does NOT come up with variables!  Once you create a string correctly, it always keeps its value; it does NOT get re-interpreted, and have backslashes cause problems all over again, each time you pass the value to a function, so `open(myvar)` should see exactly the same string you get when you `print(myvar)`.

(I think that on Windows you may also be able to just use forward slashes, which require no special quoting:)

```
'D:/Folder/2010/file.pdf'
```

Comment: Actually - os.path is one of the issues. I'm using it to write all filepaths into a list, so I have a list with paths that look like this:
D:\\Folder\\file.pdf

Then I'd like to open each file in a for loop:
`for file in filenames:`

Comment: Duh, hit enter... anyway:
`for file in filenames:
    PdfFileReader(file(file, 'rb'))`

That's what I meant in my question before, as I can't just write rfile here, and I get the paths from os.path so I can't change the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically converts forward slashes to back slashes in Windows pathnames (This is because other OSes that Python runs on, including Linux and Mac, use forward slashes natively).